# Meaning of this statement

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, reporting-services

I have been given SQL statements to use when creating my SSRS reports. I am first trying to convert them to T-SQL and then adding them to my report. I am fairly new to writing reports and learning as I go. However, I am not able to understand this statement.

I understand that these are my filters to my report, but I am not able to understand what this statement means. I realize the we are trying to make the student id equal to current student id, but I don't know if that the right way and if so how do I add this to my report.

```
strSQL = strSQL & " where student.Studentid=" & objApp.CurrentStudentID
```

Answer (score 0):

you can parameterize your queries by using `:`

```
select * from t where Gender=:Gender
```

where `:Gender` is your query parameter. Once you add parameterized query in your dataset, it will be automatically added to your parameters and when your run your Report the parameter will be asked to user.

Please note that `:` may differ by SQL Driver or by DBMS system. It is sometimes `@` or even `?id?` or `?`

Comment: what is `objApp.CurrentStudentID`? and where is the value coming from?

Comment: user has to navigate to a tab and select student table. then all the individual student id would show and when the user clicks on the student id which generates the report.